# Get Google Group member's email delivery status

Tags: google-groups, google-groups-api

Within a group (using the web/gui), you can see 'bouncing', 'non-verified' etc. etc. next to a user.
Is there a way to get this info via the API?

Using python, I can use RetrieveAllMembers to ... retrieve all members.  The returned GroupMemberEntry objects don't have the 'status' (for lack of a better word) of the user.

My goal is:
1) Dump all groups in my domain 
2) Check group for bouncing addresses
3) Email group owner about the bad addresses/users.

I can do #1 and #3.  It's #2 that I need help with.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, neither the Google Apps Provisioning API nor the Google Groups Settings API support retrieving or setting a members delivery status.

Comment: Argh...
Yet another instance of where the admin gui/dashboard has features that the API does not (and vice versa).  So there's no way then to clean up groups programatically/via the API?  Sigh.

Comment: There is no way to do this via the API today, no.